# Why Are My Facebook 'Likes' Disappearing?

Tags: facebook

[image: I'm sure my website has 21 likes, and when the page is still loading it shows 21 likes under the Twitter button]

If you [look at my website](http://www.glamourunderground.com/1038/still-looking-for-mr-right/), it shows only one Facebook Like, but while the page is loading it sometimes shows more; and I'm sure there are at least 20.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe system glitch. It happens sometimes and likes goes down to 0 to some low random number.

Answer (score 1):

When I look at your website home page http://www.glamourunderground.com/ I see **40 Facebook Likes**.

The link that you gave in your question was for a single page associated with a  post on your website. That post didn't show any Likes. But it belonged to the [**article category**](http://www.glamourunderground.com/category/articles/) of your website, which does show a positive numbers of Facebook Likes. 
Another category, [**book reviews**](http://www.glamourunderground.com/category/reviews/book-reviews/) has Likes. And [**this particular book review**](http://www.glamourunderground.com/773/free-ebooks/) also has several Likes.

So your Facebook Likes haven't gone away, but they are associated with different parts of your website due to how it is laid out (I assume).